# How can I make my Vuetify layout use all the available vertical space?

Tags: layout, flexbox, vuetify.js

I inherited a project where I need the layout to use as much viewport space as possible both horizontally and vertically, and resize nicely too.

My layout is pretty simple, with 2 main rows split in two columns. I need to make it so the two main "cells" (marked "Main 1" and "Main 2" in the code below) expand vertically to use as much vertical space as possible.

My understanding is this can be achieved using a `<v-container fluid fill-height>`. But while the horizontal part works perfectly well, I can't get this layout to expand vertically.

Here is my `App.vue` file *(simplified for the purpose of this post)*:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-main>
            <v-container fluid fill-height>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="6" class="yellow">Header 1</v-col>
                    <v-col cols="6" class="yellow">Header 2</v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="8" class="pink">
                        <v-row>
                            <v-col cols="5" class="red">Main 1</v-col>
                            <v-col cols="7" class="red">Main 2</v-col>
                        </v-row>
                        <v-row>
                            <v-col cols="12" class="red">Bottom</v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" class="pink">Right</v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .yellow {  border: 1px dotted yellow  }
  .red {  border: 1px dotted red  }
  .pink {  border: 1px dotted pink  }
</style>

<script setup>

</script>
```

I also did set up [a Vuetify playground for live testing](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

Comment: You have an issue with your markup to begin with: Vuetify uses 12 point grid system, meaining the sum of a row's columns can't be over 12. In your case you have 6, 6, 8, 4 in your main row, and 5, 7, 12 in the inner row. Each group of extra columns will wrap onto a new line. So first you have to change the markup, with extra rows and/or containers. Read more about Vutify grid system here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/ and pay special attention to nested grids.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

I just fixed my markup, so now each ```<v-row>``` has exactly 12 cols. Sadly it doesn't change fix my vertical space problem at all. Do you have any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: Just add class="fullHeight" to your row, and add this to your styles: .fullHeight { height: 100vh; width: 100vw }

Comment: That sort of works. 100% is too much height for the main row, which means the whole page is now more than 100% height, causing scroll. And 80% means not all the space will be filled. It's good enough though, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I hope this is what you were looking for. Notice how I made use of Vuetify's flex utility classes on the container and some of the rows. These classes are there to help you layout your page with flexbox. You can read more about it [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/).

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-main class='d-flex'>
            <v-container fluid fill-height class='d-flex flex-column'>
                <v-row class='flex-grow-0'>
                    <v-col cols="6" class="yellow">Header 1</v-col>
                    <v-col cols="6" class="yellow">Header 2</v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="8" class="pink d-flex flex-column">
                        <v-row>
                            <v-col cols="5" class="red">Main 1</v-col>
                            <v-col cols="7" class="red">Main 2</v-col>
                        </v-row>
                        <v-row class='flex-grow-0'>
                            <v-col cols="12" class="red">Bottom</v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" class="pink">Right</v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: This is exactly the result I was looking for. I'm still not completely clear on what the class "flex-grow-0" does, so I'm gonna play around with it. Thanks a lot for your precious help!